n*n table colored black and white arbitrary, 3 corners are white and the other one is black, show that there exists a 2*2 with an odd number of white
Consider a $n * n$ table such that the unit squares are colored arbitrarily in black and white, such that exactly three of the squares placed in the corners of the table are white, and the other one is black. Prove that there exists a $2 * 2$ square, which contains an odd number of white-colored unit squares.
This problem is from a Romanian competition held in 2007.
It's clear that the main point of solving the problem is because of the odd white-colored cells in the corners, the only counterexample I could find  is when the grid is checkered, but I don't know how to get forward, I was thinking about assuming there doesn't exist any, and then show that for it to happen the corners can't have an odd number of white squares in them, but I couldn't reach a good contradiction
Checkered coloring means coloring the cell at $(i, j)$ based on $i + j \bmod{2}$. if it was odd color it black, otherwise white, like a chessboard.

Have you looked at it for small $n$?  And...what do you mean by "the only counterexample is checkered coloring"?

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Let us think of the table as a square matrix. Assume that all $2\times 2$ squares have even number of whites. Then any $2\times2$ submatrix has even number of whites. This is because the symmetric difference of any two $2\times2$ submatrices with even number of whites that share exactly one row or exactly one column is another $2\times2$ submatrix with even number of whites. In particular, this means that the $2\times2$ submatrix formed by the corners has an even number of whites, a contradiction!

Here’s another proof:
Let’s assign $1$ to each white cell and $0$ to each black cell. Assume that all $2\times2$ squares have even number of $1$s. Then the sum over all the entries in all the $2\times2$ squares is even. The parity of the result depends only on the sum of entries in the corners because every other cell appears an even number of times in this sum. But there are odd number of $1$s in the corners, again a contradiction!
